# Is it possible to use zkSync in Polygon Mumbai?

Tags: hardhat, testnets, polygon, zksync

I am setting up a project using `zkSync` and I am seeing that, in the `hardhat.config.ts` file, the supported network is `zkSyncTestnet`.

**hardhat.config.ts**

```
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy";
    import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc";
    
    module.exports = {
      zksolc: {
        version: "1.3.1",
        compilerSource: "binary",
        settings: {},
      },
      defaultNetwork: "zkSyncTestnet",
    
      networks: {
        zkSyncTestnet: {
          url: "https://zksync2-testnet.zksync.dev",
          ethNetwork: "goerli", // Can also be the RPC URL of the network (e.g. `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<API_KEY>`)
          zksync: true,
        },
      },
      solidity: {
        version: "0.8.17",
      },
    };
```

Is it possible to use Polygon Mumbai for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment it is not possible to use `zkSync` in other networks:

```
Error in plugin @matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy: Only deploying to zkSync network is supported.
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes you can have a project configured for zkSync and other blockchains. You just have to include the attribute `zksync: true` or `zksync: false` to all the networks in your project.

This is how your config would be for both zkSync and Polygon Mumbai:

```typescript
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";

import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy";
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc";

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  zksolc: {
    version: "1.3.1",
    compilerSource: "binary",
    settings: {},
  },
  defaultNetwork: "zkSyncTestnet", //could be any of the networks below
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      zksync: false,
    },
    mumbai:{
      url: 'https://your-polygon-mumbai-endpoint.com/abcdef12345',
      zksync: false,
    },
    zkSyncTestnet: {
      url: "https://zksync2-testnet.zksync.dev",
      ethNetwork: "goerli",  // or a Goerli RPC endpoint 
      zksync: true,
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.17",
  },
```

Comment: If I do that I get: `CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling with `--via-ir` (cli) or the equivalent `viaIR: true` (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables.
   --> @matterlabs/zksync-contracts/l2/system-contracts/BootloaderUtilities.sol:103:34:
    |
103 |             uint256 listLength = encodedNonce.length +
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed`

Comment: Do I have to change the deploy scripts if I want to use a different network? Because I am seeing that I am using `@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy` in it.

Comment: For the compilation error, try adding the `isSystem: true` in the config file ([More info here](https://v2-docs.zksync.io/api/hardhat/hardhat-zksync-solc.html#configuration)). If he problem persist, I suggest to create a ticket in our Discord: https://join.zksync.dev/

Comment: For the deploy scripts, yes you have to create specific deployment scripts for zkSync as deployments are different behind the scenes. Here is a Hardhat migration guide that I think would help: https://v2-docs.zksync.io/api/hardhat/migrating-to-zksync.html#overview